# Blob MIME type incorrect for JPEG image

Tags: javascript, fetch, blob, mime-types

I'm trying to fetch a local jpg image and convert to blob. The expected MIME type for the blob is "image/jpeg" but my logs are showing it is "text/html". Please let me know if I should add additional parameters to the code below to ensure it returns a blob in the correct type:

```
const image = fetch('../images/image.jpg')
        .then((res) => res.blob())
        .then(async(myBlob) => {
            console.log(myBlob);
            //Do stuff with myblob... should be in "image/jpeg" type but showing as "text/html"
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure the response isn’t a _404 Not Found_ HTML page? This should work correctly, otherwise. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Amend the URL accordingly. You can also inspect the MIME type and the content of the response.